# How Can I Safely Update My Intel Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 Graphics Driver?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, updates, graphics, intel

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and everything is working well except my external monitor. It's somewhat glitchy when I move windows around in it. Also, its resolution is lower than it should be. It's currently at 1024 x 768 (the highest resolution option in the "displays" setting window), but it should be 1200 or so in width.

Here is my graphics/driver information:

My driver is Intel Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2. (From the "Details" section of the settings)

Also, when I typed "lspci | grep VGA" into the terminal, I got this: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

I'm thinking that I have incorrect or out of date drivers. My problem, though, is I don't know how or where to find the correct drivers. I spent a lot of time installing an Intel Driver Repository only to run it and find out that my distribution (Ubuntu 12.04) is not supported.

I hear there are ways of forcing the repository to update your drivers, but it requires using PPAs, which I've heard are risky.

I also went to https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads and did a search for ironlake, which brought up some links. They're possibly the drivers I'm looking for, but I don't know if they're the right ones and I don't want to mess anything up by just installing things willy nilly (also, I'm not super clear on how I would go about installing them in the first place).

I know there are a lot of similar issues on here, so I won't be surprised if this gets no response. But I'd really like to get my Ubuntu system up and running nicely, so I thought I'd give this a shot.

I'll keep looking around for other solutions. Hopefully I don't ruin anything.

Thanks,
Blake